# Excel Macro error prompting Save As dialog box with weird file name

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba, macros, filenames, save-as

I made a code for a friend something like this :

```
Sub SaveToMainData()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

pfn = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Backup\MainData.xlsb"

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA") 
    .Visible = True
    .Copy
    .Visible = False
End With

    With ActiveWorkbook
        .SaveAs Filename:=pfn, FileFormat:=xlExcel12
        .Close savechanges:=False
        MsgBox "Data Saved"
    End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

The sub above is called from other sub which used for input to sheet DATA then it call the sub above to copy sheet DATA as a new workbook then save this new workbook as MainData.xlsb.

I've tested within my computer at home many many times, and I don't have any problem. The sub above always run successfully without any funny thing happen.

But, the funny thing happened sometimes when my friend use the workbook (and run the sub which call the sub above) in his office. The Save As dialog box appear with a weird file name like below :
[image]

When I asked my friend what did he do before that, he say he just use the workbook as ussual. Then sometimes after he run the sub which call the macro above, the dialog box like above appear. So, he said he just save it then directly close the workbook. He never remember whether the msgbox "Data Saved" has the chance to show or not.

I'm unable to find a way /a process to do something deliberatly in order that kind of dialog box appear after I call the macro which call the sub above.

I have searched the internet with a keyword similar with the title of my question here, but I can't find the answer, maybe because I don't put a right keyword in English.

So my question here, would someone please tell me in what kind of situation, the Save As dialogue box already filled with a weird file name is shown like the image above?

Any kind of response would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advanced.

---

After following the suggestion from @harrymc, I still can't replicate the things which will cause the SaveAs dialog box appear similar like the image above.

It seems that Excel did catch the line ".SaveAs Filename:=pfn, **FileFormat:=xlExcel12**" hence : the directory is correct, the file Save As Type in the dialog box is "Excel Binary Workbook" without "(*.xlsb)" extension .... but somehow Excel change the file name with a weird name without extension (such as : 3E371C00, CB60EB00, 78850B00, and so on).

I've tried also to rename that weird name, so it become something like "3E371C00.xlsb". And I can open it with Excel App.

Comment: Is it possible that the file already exists and is not writable (opened by another program)?

Comment: @harrymc, thank you for your comment. So, using my neighbour's laptop, I share the folder, and the laptop open "MainData.xlsb". Within my computer I run the sub in question, it did throw an error saying that MainData.xlsb is already open. So I click END on the error-debug-window, and directly quit Excel App. But the popup SaveAs dialog box filled with a normal file name, such as `Book1.xlsx` not funny name like `3E371C00`, the Save As Type is `Excel Workbook (*.xlsx)` - not `Excel Binary Workbook`, and the default dir is `Documents` not `D:\Data Share\...\Backup`.